# Swift 4 and Firebase appending all posts with username and profile image error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue, I can append all the posts into my collection view but the username and profileImage change to whoever the currently logged in user is. Can someone help me figure out how to set it to the user who posted it?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var cellId = "cellId"

    var filteredPosts = [Post]()
    var posts = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleUpdateFeed), name: PostController.updateFeedNotificationName, object: nil)

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1)

        collectionView?.register(HomePostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionView?.refreshControl = refreshControl

        setupNavigationItems()

        fetchPosts()
    }

    @objc func handleUpdateFeed() {
        handleRefresh()
    }

    fileprivate func fetchPosts() {
        guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else { return }

        FIRDatabase.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid) { (user) in
            self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
        }
    }


    fileprivate func fetchPostsWithUser(user: User) {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                else { return }

            dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in

                guard let userDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: userDictionary)

                self.posts.append(post)
            })

            self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                return post1.creationDate.compare(post2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
            })

            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch posts.",err)
        }
        }

    @objc func handleRefresh() {
        self.posts.removeAll()
        self.fetchPosts()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        }
    }

    func setupNavigationItems() {
        navigationItem.title = "Events"
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "download").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleFilter))
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomePostCell

        cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
    }
import UIKit

class HomePostCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var post: Post? {
        didSet{

            usernameLabel.text = post?.user.username

            guard let profileImageUrl = post?.user.profileImageUrl else { return }

            userProfileImageView.loadImage(urlString: profileImageUrl)

            setupCaptionText()
            setupDateLabel()
        }
    }

    let userProfileImageView: CustomImageView = {
        let iv = CustomImageView()
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return iv
    }()

    let usernameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return label
    }()
    let captionLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        return label
    }()

    let dateLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return label
    }()

    let optionsButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("•••", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        return button
    }()

    fileprivate func setupCaptionText() {
        guard let post = self.post else { return }

        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " \(post.caption)", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)])

        captionLabel.attributedText = attributedText
    }

    fileprivate func setupDateLabel() {
    guard let post = self.post else { return }

        let timeAgoDisplay = post.creationDate.timeAgoDisplay()
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: timeAgoDisplay, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray])

        dateLabel.attributedText = attributedText
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(userProfileImageView)
        userProfileImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 5, paddingRight: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        userProfileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40 / 2

        backgroundColor = .white

        addSubview(usernameLabel)
        usernameLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: userProfileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 12, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        addSubview(captionLabel)
        captionLabel.anchor(top: userProfileImageView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        addSubview(optionsButton)
        optionsButton.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 10, width: 0, height: 0)

        addSubview(dateLabel)
        dateLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 5, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

import Foundation

struct User {
    var uid: String
    let username: String
    let profileImageUrl: String

    init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.username = dictionary["usernames"] as? String ?? ""
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"]  as? String ?? ""
    }
}

import Foundation

struct Post {

    var id: String?

    let user: User
    let caption: String
    let creationDate: Date


    init(user: User, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.user = user
        self.caption = dictionary["caption"] as? String ?? ""

        let secondsFrom1970 = dictionary["creationDate"] as? Double ?? 0
        self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFrom1970)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here:

```
 fileprivate func fetchPosts() {
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else { return }

    FIRDatabase.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid) { (user) in
        self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
    }
}
```

You're basically making a query based on the `currentUser?.uid` and not on the user that created the post. You're passing that to the `fileprivate func fetchPostsWithUser(user: User)` hence it retrieves the same logged in user.

It actually should pass the `user.uid` stored for each post on the database (unless you want to pull out the posts for the `currentUser` and display those.

Each post at the moment of posting needs to store the user `uid` and store that on the database. Then make query to get those posts based on the `uid` of the user. And cache your users in an array just like you did with your posts.

**UPDATED:**

```
class Post {

var id           : String?
var title        : String?
var content      : String?
var userUid      : String? 

static func transformDataToPost (dictionary: [String : Any], key: String) -> Post {
    let post = Post()
    post.id        = key // this is the snapshot.key that you get
    post.userUid   = dictionary["userUid"] as? String
    post.title     = dictionary["title"] as? String
    post.content   = dictionary["content"] as? String
    return
}
```

Now, when observing the post to get data back from `Firebase` I'm using it a little more structured, in another class, ie, I have separate `PostApi` class where I deal with all `API` requests, not in the `UIViewController` itself, but the idea is the same.

```
var REF_POSTS = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

func observePost(withId id: String, completion: @escaping (Post) -> Void) {
    REF_POSTS.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            let post = Post.transformDataToPost(dictionary: dictionary, key: snapshot.key)
            completion(post)
        }
    })
}
```

For sending the data to `FirebaseDatabase` I do it the following way:

```
static func sendPostDataToDatabase ( title: String?,
                                   content: String?,
                                   onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void,
                                   onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {

    let newPostId = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.childByAutoId().key  // THIS creates the new ID of a post, it's just a dynamic way to get a unique post ID , you can also use  NSUUID().uuidString which will give you a unique string

    // the definition of `uuidString` is: A string containing a formatted UUID for example E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F. 

    let newPostReference = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.child(newPostId) 

    // MARK: - TIMESTAMP FEATURE
    let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

    var newPostDict = [    "userUid"      : Api.Users.CURRENT_USER!.uid,
                           "title"        : title as Any,
                           "content"      : content as Any,
                           "timestamp"    : timestamp
                        ] as [String : Any]

      newPostReference.setValue(newPostDict) { (error, databaseRef) in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        else {
            onSuccess(newShipId, photosArray[0])
        }
    }
```

Comment: After I store the user uid, would the reference to get the uid be something like, Guard let uid = firdatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child("user.uid")

Comment: That depends on how you store your information (you haven't posted your code where you store/upload your data to `Firebase Database`), but  basing on your `Post` model it will be like this: 
`firdatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(postId).child("user.uid")` and the key of this would give you the `user.uid` of the post

Comment: FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid)
            ref.updateChildValues(values) that's how I'm saving my posts in the database uid is set to the current users id from FIRAuth, Also Vaules is just set to ["caption": caption, "creationDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970] as [String : Any]

Comment: Okay, so you're using the `user.uid` to store each unique post. I'd recommend using the `post.id` instead. What happens when the same user tries to post a second post? The post gets the same id since the `user.uid` never changes, does it? instead of doing it that way, im using `let newPostIdString = NSUUID().uuidString` which generates a unique id for each post that the user creates. Do you see the flaw in your logic? I'm not sure because I haven't tested it, but I assume it overwrites the previous post because of the same ID

Comment: Yes I do, Just to confirm. I should create the newPostIdString = NSUUID().uuidString instead of the uid statement i have. Then place that into the firbase call in place of the uid too.

Comment: Yes, make sure your posts have an actual unique ID instead of a user.uid. You can still store the `user.uid` inside the post, as an additional `key: value` pair, that's what I do and I know many others do, but don't store the `user.uid` as your `post.id` because DOES NOT create a `unique` ID

Comment: Do I add the NSUUID().uuidString to the post struct instead of the uid?

Comment: No, see my updated answer, it gives you more details on how I go for implementing this. I hope that shows more

Comment: Is the Class Post replacing my post struct?

Comment: I just showed you an example, you don't have to copy it exactly the same, it was just to show you how it works and the flaw of your logic really.